# How to navigate using prism 5 with Unity?

Tags: wpf, prism

The quick start prism5 `Navigation` example from MSDN usded `MEF` codes I am not very familiar with. If I wanna use `Unity` instead, how to change the implementation `IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification` interface?

Actually why can't I just put all the codes `IRegion mainContentRegion = this.regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainContentRegion];...`
inside the constructor of the view?

```
public CalendarNavigationItemView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

void IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification.OnImportsSatisfied()
{
    IRegion mainContentRegion = this.regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainContentRegion];
    if (mainContentRegion != null && mainContentRegion.NavigationService != null)
    {
        mainContentRegion.NavigationService.Navigated += this.MainContentRegion_Navigated;
    }
}
```